# Spring RESTful Date format

Tags: json, spring, rest, jackson

A rest controller in jdk8 like this

```
@Transactional
@RequestMapping(value="/A", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ABean aInsert(final java.sql.Date when, final long company) {
  A bean = new A();
  bean.setWhen(when);
  bean.setCompany(entityManager.find(Company.class, company));
  entityManager.persist(bean);
  return new ABean(bean.getId(), bean.getVersion(), bean.getWhen(), bean.getCompany().getId());
}
```

is called with form post-data

```
when=1459987200000&company=1
```

but can not be called and returns a `400 - bad request
 (description The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.)`.

My question is:

- What is the default input string format of the `java.sql.date`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`when=2016-04-21&company=10` Works, so its

```
yyyy-mm-dd
```

For every other format register a custom [Converter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/convert/converter/Converter.html) like this:

```
@Autowired
private final ConfigurableConversionService conversionService=null;

@PostConstruct
public void registerConverter() {
    conversionService.addConverter(new Converter<String, Long>() {
        @Override
        public Long convert(String source) {
            try {
                SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd'T'hh:mm");
                return df.parse(source).getTime();
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                return Long.parseLong(source);
            }
        }
    });
}
```